# Pyramid: Views registered with `view_config` not being associated with routes

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm declaring a route like this:

```
from my_package import views
config.add_route("hello", "/hello")
config.scan(views)
```

And in `my_package.views` I have the view:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
@view_config(name="hello")
def hello(request):
    return Response("Hello, world!")
```

But route isn't being associated with the view.

Specifically, checking routes in the debug toolbar shows that no view callable is associated with the `hello` route, and visiting `/hello` returns a 404.

Changing the route definition to something like `config.add_route("hello", "/hello", views.hello)` works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `config` symbol coming from in your first code snippet? You don't have two separate config objects in play or anything, do you?

Comment: I doubt that it's two `config` symbols… The lines are adjacent in my source file (just like in the example), and when I comment out the `config.scan(views)` and explicitly add the view callable to the route, everything works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are naming the *view*, not the *route* in your @view_config decorator. You want:

```
@view_config(route_name='hello')
def hello(request):
    return Response("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: FFFFUUUUU *facepalm* Thanks :)

Comment: What is the name of a view used for? Looking at [the docs](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/view.html), it seems like it can be used to lookup views (ie, with `render_view_to_response`)… Anything else?